# How to iterate over all elements in array(or list) with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, iteration, containers

I am new to LINQ and i want to switch onto it from traditional loops
I have an array of GameObjects and I just want to iterate over all of them and set one of their component enabled, and I wanna know if there is 1 line elegant way with LINQ to replace foreach or for loop's version

Comment: Sure. Actually linq is all about this. The method you are looking for is ForEach. But you need first to add using System.Linq. Anyway, I recommend you first to read about linq.

Comment: Before using `List<T>.ForEach()`, please take a moment to read through this article from a decade ago, still relevant: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gameObjects.ToList().ForEach(x => {do Stuff with list});`

Some reading on forEach in C# however. Could be interesting: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/04/08/why-i-dont-use-the-foreach-extension-method/

Comment: so are you suggesting that using linq version of foreach is bad practice?